# How to remove prefixes from bibliography while using multibib?

Tags: bibliographies, citing, ieee-style, multibib

I want to use IEEE styled referencing using "multibib" package. I have 2 types of references, one with international publications, stacked in a bib file named int.bib, and the other named nat.bib where papers from national institutes are stacked. I am making the bibliography in two sections, National status and International Status. I would like to get the references as numbers in square braces, but I am getting a prefix with the numbers matching the name of the sections. I would like to get rid of the prefixes.

```
%Header footer

\usepackage[margin=0.8in,left=0.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

%Bibliography
% \usepackage[
% backend=biber,
% %style=bwl-FU,
% %style=ynt,
% %citestyle=authoryear
% sorting=ynt
% ]{biblatex}
% \addbibresource{dstbib.bib}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[resetlabels,labeled]{multibib}
\newcites{int}{International Status}
\newcites{nat}{National Status}

\begin{document}
%Other things%
\section{Bibliography}
    \bibliographystyleint{plain}
    \bibliographyint{dstbib_int.bib}

    \bibliographystylenat{plain}
    \bibliographynat{dstbib_nat.bib}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone finding this in the future, changing:

```
\usepackage[resetlabels,labeled]{multibib}
```

To:

```
\usepackage[resetlabels]{multibib}
```

Fixed this problem for me.